# IONIC: unable to build app after installing `cordova-plugin-fcm`

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new with ionic framework.Currently i am working on `ionicsidemenu` android  app.  I want notification in my app for this i have installed `cordova-plugin-fcm` plugin.    After installing plugin when i run `ionic run android` it gives build failed message with below  error

[image: Build error]

I have configured my app in `firebase console`.   I have plugins in my app :

[image: Plugin list]

Please help me.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your platforms/android/project.properties should be changed like this:

```
target=android-25

android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/courseur-xwalk.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-firebase/courseur-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0
cordova.system.library.7=com.android.support:support-v4:+
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+
```

Comment: Hello @Roy when i tried your solution getting error  `Could not read script courseur-xwalk.gradle as it does not exists`.

Comment: try removing it

Comment: I have removed it,  still getting error could not read  `cordova-plugin-firebase/courseur-build.gradle` .   I removed it also,  i am getting a long stack trace and build failed.

Comment: post your project.properties

Comment: the initial one which failed before making these changes @NupurJain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145115/discussion-between-nupur-jain-and-roy).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the The Google Play Services SDK installed.

On my MAC, I use Android Studio -> Configure (at the bottom) -> SDK Manager.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1 (for FCM Plugin)
Comment out these lines in the FCMPlugin.gradle file.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
```

Step 2 (for FCM Plugin)
Change the plugin.xml of the FCM plugin to use a different version, in my situation 9.8.0.

```
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0" />
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0" />
```

Step 3 (for Background-Geolocation-Plugin)
Change the plugin.xml of the Geolocation plugin to use a different version, in my situation 9.8.0 instead of "+".

```
<framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0" />
```

Step 4
Remove and re-add plattform.

Step 5 (build.gradle file of the android platform folder)
Add this line to the classpath section

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

And add this line below the dependencies, nearly at the bottom of the file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```